# Search using multiple conditions with the IN Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am basically trying to retrieve data and do some steps when 3 conditions are met. I have a table say contact columns (contactid (PrimaryKey), personid, firstname , lastname,email)
Now I am basically trying to find the primary key i.e. the Contactid of the employees when multiple conditions are met i.e. where firstname = 'abc' and email = 'abc@yahoo.com'. Now the issue mainly is because this table can have duplicates and employees might have more than 1 email address.

I was thinking of code like

```
Select * from contact where firstname IN ('','','',) and lastname IN ('','','') and emailid IN ('','','')
```

I am testing but I am still not sure basically I am confused because of the IN's that i have in the query. Does the code gets sequentially executed in this case? Or if u can help me with some other approach that would be great.

Comment: you're speaking about 3 conditions, what are they?

Comment: @IlyaBursov -
Select * from contact where firstname IN ('','','',) and lastname IN ('','','') and emailid IN ('','','')

Comment: ok, why do you have 3 empty values in every `in`?

Comment: @IlyaBursov- Empty just for demonstration

But here is an example. So ABC - ABCLASTNAME - ABC@yahoo.com . These are the 3 conditions which are supposed to meet and i want to retrieve the corresponding ID for that record
Select * from contact where firstname IN ('abc','xyz','aaa',) and lastname IN ('abclastname','xyzlastname','aaalastname') and emailid IN ('abc@yahoo.com','xyz@yahoo.com','aaa@yahoo.com')

Comment: I don't understand your example, you have `abc` for first name, `abclastname` for lastname and `abc@yahoo.com` for email, where did you get `xyz,aaa` in query?

Comment: The way you have it written you will get any combination of names and emails in that list. For example: firstname='abc', lastname='xyzlastname', and  emailid='aaa@yahoo.com' would be a valid result. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: So i have 1000 firstname , 1000 corresponding lastnames and 1000 corresponding email addresses .
Now i need to write a query to find the Contactid (Primary Key) from the contact table when these 3 criteria match. 

Without the IN statement we would write the query like this.

Select * from contact where firstname = 'abc' and lastname = 'abclastname' and emailid = 'abc@yahoo.com'

Now i do not want to write 1000 select queries that is why i was writing them all with a IN statement. Is it clearer now ?

Comment: ok, then @kaineub is right, you cannot just supply them in IN statements, you need to write something like that `select * from table where (first=A1 and last=B1 and email=C1) OR (first=A2 and last=B2 and email=C2)`

Comment: @kaineub - No I want the combination of firstname = 'abc', lastname = 'abclastname' and email ='abc@yahoo.com'

Thats what  is basically confusing me , How can i do a match when using the IN statement

Comment: @IlyaBursov - Yea thats what i thought. That will be painful over 1000 select statements

Comment: I don't understand why you think that it will be more painful that IN variant, in both cases you will write some code to generate SQL based on user supplied dataset, it is absolutely the same level of effort to generate any of these statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is something like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM contact
WHERE (firstname = 'fname1' AND lastname = 'lname1' and emailid ='email1')
   OR (firstname = 'fname2' AND lastname = 'lname2' and emailid ='email2')
   OR (firstname = 'fname3' AND lastname = 'lname3' and emailid ='email3')
```

An IN list allows for many different combinations. Not too useful for this unfortunately.

Another option would be to put the allowed combinations in a separate table and use a JOIN:

```
SELECT C.*
FROM contact C JOIN allowedCombinations A
ON C.firstname = A.firstname AND C.lastname = A.lastname AND C.emailid = A.emailid
```

Comment: Brilliant idea for the Join .. I will try that out dint strike me at first